# Iframe basic-authentication

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, basic-authentication

I'm using an iframe in one of my webpages.
The page i'm calling is protected witrh a static username and password.

Example of the issue:
[image: example of the issue]

Is there a way I can authenticate without promting the login popup to the user?

I guess somethig like https://user:pass@host/ would work, but all browser block this kind of requests because of security issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Credentials as part of the URL will get blocked by browsers these days, yes. If the resource can't be made available unprotected (why protect it in the first place, when the credentials will be exposed in client-side code?), then I guess you could only try and proxy those requests. Not sure if that is possible client-side in this scenario (service workers can intercept and manipulate requests - but I think that is for the current document only?); if not, you would have to do it on the server side.